# These Statements take too much time in mysql Procedure?

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

MySQL Procedure statement too much time can any one guide me how to solve it. these statement take more then 13 minutes to execute. when i remove these statements from procedure then procedure take 1 second to execute.

```
if(pb.iLab = 1,
        0,
        ifnull(
           (SELECT sum(p_bi.dTotalAmount) amount
              FROM patientbillitem p_bi, patientbillpayment p_b
             WHERE     p_bi.vRefReceipt = p_b.vReceiptNo
                   AND p_b.iBillNo = pb.iBillNo
                   AND p_bi.vItemCode = pbi.vItemCode),
           0))
   - (ifnull(
         (SELECT sum(p_bi.discountAmount) amount
            FROM patientbillitem p_bi, patientbillpayment p_b
           WHERE     p_bi.vRefReceipt = p_b.vReceiptNo
                 AND p_b.iBillNo = pb.iBillNo
                 AND p_bi.vItemCode = pbi.vItemCode),
         0))
      dRefund,
```

any one guide me any other method to write this dRefund in select statement thank you.

Comment: need to see the fully query.  I don't like putting selects statements in the select itself... so I'd likely try to figure out how to get the sum for all the records at once in inline views then reference those fields instead of running a separate select for each record returned... twice.  end result would be something like `if(pb.iLab = 1,0, ifnull(Amount1,0) - (ifnull(Amount2,0)) dRefund`

Comment: Why can't you pull back the dTotalAmont and discountAmount in your main query, below where you reference them now? You could calculate this in around the 1 second time frame aggregating up on a group from your main query. If it looks too complicated to do then you can use a sub query or two. Having queries in your select statement the way you have now can send the optimizer into a tailspin.